# Why does `SW_HIDE` leave a ghost after forcibly setting a game's window style to `WS_POPUP`?

Tags: winapi, user32, showwindow

I am trying to hide Factorio window after removing its border by setting its style to `WS_POPUP`. When I call `ShowWindow(factorio, SW_HIDE)` the window leaves behind a black box, that is transparent to clicks, can not be activated, does not appear in the taskbar, but keeps being rendered where the original window would be (including z-order).

Comment: Maybe it uses a separate alphablended window to provide a frame?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I don't think so. If I don't change the style it disappears normally.

Comment: `Factorio` is a top-level window?Parent window or child window? And you have to note `WS_POPUP` cannot be used with the `WS_CHILD` style. Try disabling `WS_BORDER` and `WS_THICKFRAME`(`WS_SIZEBOX`) if you are using these. By the way, you'd better provide a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: I'm certainly very curious to know the answer here, sounds like yet another window manager bug. But I have a hunch that people dismiss this question because it looks like you didn't put a lot of effort into it. I would assume that you wouldn't have gotten close-votes if you had provided code and screenshots, possibly for both scenarios (with and without changing the style).